# How to call rev_list with GitPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, gitpython

This program fails

```
import git

repo = git.repo.Repo('..')
res = repo.git.rev_list('--since="2024-01-01" master').split('\n')
```

with the following error

```
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(129)
cmdline: git rev-list --since="2024-01-01" master
stderr: 'usage: git rev-list [<options>] <commit>... [--] [<path>...]
```

despite that the command `git rev-list --since="2024-01-01" master` works just fine from the command line.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are misuing the `repo.git.rev_list` method. The first argument is meant to be a branch name (or other commit reference). You are effectively running the command:

```
['git', 'rev-list', '--since="2024-01-01" master']
```

Which is to say, you're looking for a branch or other reference with the literal name `--since="2024-01-01" master`. You should get the result you expect if you spell the command like this:

```
res = repo.git.rev_list("master", since="2024-01-01").split('\n')
```

Although on my system I had to be explicit and use `refs/heads/master` to avoid a `warning: refname 'master' is ambiguous.` message from git.

---

Instead of using `git rev-list`, you could also do this entirely using the GitPython API:

```py
import git
from datetime import datetime

repo = git.repo.Repo('.')
d =datetime.strptime('2024-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
ts = int(d.timestamp())
commits = [
  commit for commit in repo.iter_commits('refs/heads/master')
  if commit.committed_date > d.timestamp()
]
```

Or if you want just the hex sha values:

```py
commits = [
  commit.hexsha for commit in repo.iter_commits('refs/heads/master')
  if commit.committed_date > d.timestamp()
]
```